# UPDATE SET CASE with an INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a field in one of our relational tables. The table in question is a user-skill relationship table. The field I'm trying to update is the proficiency field.

I have an array in PHP with the name of the skill as the key and the proficiency as the value.

Here's the SQL Statement I'm running.

```
UPDATE rus 
SET proficiency = CASE 
    WHEN ls.name = 'Objective-C' THEN 'Beginner' 
    END 
FROM rel_users_li_skills rus INNER JOIN li_skills ls ON ls.id = rus.skill_id 
WHERE rus.user_id = 3852
```

The PHP array is enumerated through to add extra `WHEN ls.name = 'skill-name' THEN 'proficiency'` statements in the CASE statement.

The problem I'm having is the following :

check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM rel_users_li_skills rus INNER JOIN li_skills ls ON ls.id = rus.skill_id WHE' at line 1

I'm stumped on this one. I've found a couple of SO posts and forums already that seem to use the same syntax and have no problems.

Comment: does your example fail or just the code generated by PHP?

Comment: @web_bod the same query run via the mysql console fires the same error. PHP is generating the query that I'm expecting to work.

Comment: This is syntax as used by sql server (check the tags). [MySql does that differently](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html), but i'm not using it so I'm unsure how exactly it would be written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MySQL`, unlike `SQL Server`, you don't need to refer the target table in `FROM`:

```
UPDATE  rel_users_li_skills rus
JOIN    li_skills ls
ON      ls.id = rus.skill_id 
SET     proficiency = CASE WHEN ls.name = 'Objective-C' THEN 'Beginner' END 
WHERE   rus.user_id = 3852
```

Comment: @birarda: at the same place as now.

Answer (score 1):

I usually used this kind of format.

```
UPDATE  rel_users_li_skills rus INNER JOIN li_skills ls
           ON ls.id = rus.skill_id 
   SET  proficiency = (CASE WHEN ls.name = 'Objective-C' THEN 'Beginner' END)
 WHERE  rus.user_id = 3852
```